# How to sort a pivot table obtained with the query function in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I know that it is not possible to "order by" after a pivot in query function, that is why I apply a nested query.

```
=QUERY(
QUERY(Dataset,"select B,count(B) where A>date'2019-10-01' group by B pivot year(A),month(A)",1),
"Select * order by Col2 Desc ",1)
```

However the result is not sorted by `count(B)` (Col2 of the inner query) as a total.
It is sorted only by the Col2 generated because of the pivot. The final table is sorted incorrectly (Option 10 should be in fifth place and not at the bottom).

[Example of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck4Be.png)

Any workaround to solve this?

Comment: Could you also share the data your results derive from?

Comment: They are in the link "Example of the result"

Comment: Those are your results. I am talking about the data.

Comment: No, Sorry it is not possible.

Comment: Even so. As mentioned [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367800/how-to-sort-a-pivot-table-obtained-with-the-query-function-in-google-sheet?noredirect=1#comment108565231_61369144). Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a second query use the `SORT` function outside the first query.

Try something like:

```
 =SORT(QUERY(Dataset,"select B,count(B) where A>date'2019-10-01' group by B pivot year(A),month(A)",1),2,0)
```

Comment: This gives me the same result than with the nested query. Kind of need a total column to run the sort and then split into columns with the pivot function in query, otherwise the sort is done with the first column after splitting the information.

Comment: _"This gives me the same result than with the nested query."_. Just play around with it changing `asc` and `desc` as well as the columns in the `SORT` formula by changing the number of the column used to sort by. It definitely works once you find the right combination. _(you cannot be further helped since we are not aware of your original data or a set of dummy data. If interested please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311))_